# bootstrap image resizing to screen size with in container

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap page which gives me tiles that adjust position to screen size. It all work great but I have a problem with adding images to tiles along with other items.
The below script is an example of my problem. The first tile has an image which is displayed below a check box and title. Due to this check box and title the image is placed half way outside the panel. On the second panel i only have the image and it is perfectly resized with in the panel and adjust to all screen sizes.
I have tried using CSS to specify the height of the image but this does not work on all screen sizes. If I say height:50% then it fits inside the panel for large screens but pops out the bottom on small screens.
Is there a way around this. Could I specify in CSS the size of the image for all the common screen sizes.

HTML Script

```html
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HomeControl</title>
    <!-- include bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
     <div id="tile1" class="tile">
  <p style="color:blue">Boiler On/Off</p>
        <!--Boiler on/off control-->
         <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="boilerSwitch">
    <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="boiler" id="boiler" value="1">
    <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label></div>
       <img src="../heatingCold.png"/>
    </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
  <div id="tile2" class="tile">
      <!--Niamh Room control-->
         <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
   <img src="../heatingCold.png" class="img-responsive"/></div>
   </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".tile").height($("#tile1").width());
    $(".carousel").height($("#tile1").width());
     $(".item").height($("#tile1").width());
     
    $(window).resize(function() {
    if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
 this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
  $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
 }, 10);
    });
    
    $(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
     $(".tile").height($("#tile1").width());
        $(".carousel").height($("#tile1").width());
        $(".item").height($("#tile1").width());
    });

});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: image screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `class="img-responsive"` on your second image, or was that on purpose?

You should take a look into [Bootstrap Media Queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Comment: I will look at this thanks. I did try img-responsive but this did not work. I have not used this before. By look of it it adjust the width cab it do the height of the image

Comment: `img-responsive` will scale down your image if the container gets too small. With media queries you can add styles that take effect when reaching a specific browser window width

Comment: The img-responsive is not working on the first image. Not sure if this has something to do with having a check box within the panel. If I put the following in <img src="../heatingCold.png"/ class="img-responsive"/>    I still end up with the image over hanging the bottom as shown in the image above. This is on a large monitor